# Edit the same map on Google Earth and MyMaps

Tags: google-my-maps, google-earth, kml

I would like to edit the same map on Google Earth and Google My Maps. I know that I can export KMZ to Google Earth and open it there. But what if I change the map in My Maps - I would like an automatic update in Google Earth and vice versa.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible - partially. Your maps are a part of Drive so first you need to download desktop Drive client - **https://www.google.com/drive/download/** - and enable synchronization. Then you need to setup folder from Google Earth containing maps, to be included or transferred into your Drive synchronization folder. And when done just open your **KMZ/KML** map in Google Earth, play with it and save it, which will get synchronized with your Drive and your map in MyMaps shall be auto-updated and ready to be edited from MyMaps. then just play with your map on MyMaps and when done it will be auto-updated and auto synchronized with your Drive folder on your PC so its ready to be opened and played again in Google Earth, and so on.

Comment: My google drive contains map file with extension `*.gmap` and I don't thing Google Earth will eat it

Comment: @user1128179 like I said KML/KMZ. you cant directly open gmap in earth.